# Using Wget to download files in "members only" that require password

Tags: security, wget, pdf

I am almost finished with our new web site and a customer of ours told me today about Wget.  He went on to say if someone used Wget they can log in and download the files that we have in a "members only" area which requires a password too.  Is this true?  If so, what do we need to do or be on the look out for to stop anyone from doing this?

Cheers

Comment: If someone can log in, they can download files, right? Being able to log in seems to imply having passwords. So I'm not sure what the question is about. Basically, everything you can download with wget can be downloaded with a browser. The only significant difference is that with wget it's easy to bulk download tousands of files. The countermeasure here is throttling.

Comment: If you can access files using URL without being log, it's maybe because of .htaccess or because your application is badly coded. but we can't help you without the web server configuration and the complete technical explanation which I do not advise you to put here as it could lead to sensible data leak for your company.

Answer (score 2):

So, this sounds like a question about trying to stop people from duplicating your site.

Yes, wget can download *all* front-facing parts of a website with authentication.

However, it is possible in the same way that you can *view* the files. Your server doesn't care about if it's coming from wget, or it's from a browser, it serves the HTML to be viewed by the client. There is no security issue here, as no backend (PHP, etc.) code is touched - that is parsed and controlled by the server itself, and never allowed out.

Rambling on, here's an analogy. Your email account is "members" only, right? But you can save the HTML from it (ctrl+s/cmd+s), whereupon you'll get a saved version of the page, but with none of the functionality. So someone can't hack into your email account from a saved HTML file, in the same way someone can't hack from a screenshot (unless there's a password visible in the screenshot, etc.).